# Is there a way to know which 3rd party JavaScript code is injecting HTML to my page?

Tags: javascript

A client of mine has multiple 3rd party JavaScript files that are loaded on the web site. Many of those have the capability of manipulating the HTML. In my case, there is "something" that is modifying the  tag on every page but I don't know where it is coming from. How do I figure out which piece of code or which 3rd party JS code responsible for changing the  tag?

Comment: Block the 3rd party scripts one at a time and see which one is doing it....

Answer (score 1):

You can store the state of the HTML before loading each script, then perform a check right after each script:

```html
<h1>My HTML</h1>
<script>
const state = document.body.innerHTML
</script>

<script>
// 3rd party JS code
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<h2>Injected code</h2>")
</script>

<script>
let currState = document.body.innerHTML
if(state != currState) console.log('modified at checkpoint 1')
</script>
```